# Alinhamento do list-style

Tags: css

Fala pessoal, alguém consegue me ajudar, estou com dificuldade pra alinhar o pontinho do list-style no centro da li.

Na foto, observando a última li, da pra ver que a bolinha está alinhada com o primeiro parágrafo, porém gostaria de alinhar ela ao centro das 4 linhas, se alguém souber, obrigado!

Segue a imagem abaixo para que possa ficar mais claro!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXW9s.png

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.